# Right-hand rule for fields example problem

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

For context, I've started reading "Classical Mechanics" by John Taylor and I have a small problem with one of his examples:

[image]

He gives an example of the magnetic force between two moving charges as an example of Newton's Third Law not being exactly true (as some of the mechanical momentum is going to the electromagnetic momentum of the fields). The issue I have is how he defines the direction of the magnetic field induced by the moving positive charge $q_1$. He says,

> The moving charge $q_1$ is equivalent to a current in the x direction. By the right-hand rule for fields, this produces a magnetic field which points in the z direction in the vicinity of $q_2$. By the right hand rule for forces, this field produces a force $\bf{F}_{12}$ on $q_2$  that is in the x direction.

I assumed the right-hand rule he was referring to was this:

[image]

because he goes on to state that from this field, we can find the direction of the force using the right-hand rule for forces. But wouldn't the right-hand rule I attached mean that the magnetic field acts in both the y and z axis? SO why would the magnetic field generated by $q_1$ act upwards? I know it's probably a small detail, but I would like to know thanks.

Comment: Think about field lines of $q_1$ making circles around the $x$-axis, and what direction are they going when they cross the $y$-axis where $q_2$ is.

Comment: Ah right, so it's because they're on the same plane that the field lines on that side of the current $q_1$ are pointing upwards? So if the current $q_2$ was travelling in the -y direction, the magnetic field would point down?

Comment: Yes to the first question. “Field of which charge, and where?” to the second.

Comment: Right, so in the diagram, $q_2$ is travelling along the positive y axis and so it experiencing the upwards magnetic field generated by $q_1$. Would it be true the if the charge $q_2$ was travelling instead along the -y axis, that it would experience a downwards magnetic field generated by $q_1$ because of the circular field?

Comment: No. The magnetic field of $q_1$ has nothing to do with the motion of $q_2$. On the $y$-axis, it points in the $+z$-direction regardless of which direction $q_2$ is moving. But the magnetic *force* on $q_2$ depends on both the magnetic and direction of the magnetic field at the location of $q_2$ and the magnitude and direction of the velocity of $q_2$. If you reverse $q_2$‘s velocity, you reverse the force it feels.